# Is Ubuntu 14.10 supported with Windows 8.1 preinstalled?

Tags: dual-boot

I have tried many times to install Ubuntu 14.10 on my Notebook of FUJITSU LIFEBOOK UH55/M.But it's always turned out something to be wrong, and it's just the Boot questions.

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 with UEFI, and with BOOT SECURE ON,because I want my pre-installed Win8 works between Ubuntu.

Now I doubt that Ubuntu 14.10 version is support UEFI or not,I followed many ways that INSTALL Ubuntu with SECURE BOOT ON. It seems not support my computer,by the way, if I have to try the Version 12.10?

```
OS           Windows 8.1 64 Bit.
CPU          INTEL® Core™ i5-4200U PROCESS (1.60-2.60GHz)
MEMORY       4GB(4GB×1)(DDR3L PC3L-12800)
HDD          500GB HDD (HDD＋NAND FLASH MEMORY)
DRIVE        NONE
DISPLAY     13.3 HD フルフラットファインパネル（TOUCH）[1366×768]
GRAPYICS    Intel® HD Graphics 4400
CAMERA  HD Webカメラ内蔵（有効画素数 約92万画素）
INTERNET    LANなし, ワイヤレスLAN(IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n準拠)
Bluetooth   Bluetooth® ワイヤレステクノロジー Ver.4.0+HS準拠
KEYBOARD    STANDARD KEBOARD（91KEY）
POINTING DEBASE     フラットポイント内蔵
```

Comment: See this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported It has a LOT of info and tips, read & try them first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this youtube on on installing Ubuntu with and existing windows system computer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVppdkOThCs

If you don't like Ubuntu and it doesn't work how you want it to, it is very easy to remove.